# Multiple DNS for docker

Tags: docker, docker-network

**/etc/docker/daemon.json**

```
{
  "dns": ["10.10.10.1", "10.10.10.2"]
}
```

inside docker container **/etc/resolv.conf** after `docker run -it centos:7 bash`

```
nameserver 10.10.10.1
nameserver 10.10.10.2
```

When i try to curl inside the container, it can resolve host under 10.10.10.1 nameserver but it cannot resolve host under the 2nd nameserver, 10.10.10.2.

I can verify this by swapping the order from the two nameserver in daemon.json or resolv.conf inside container.

The goal is to **resolve hostname from both nameservers**

I have dnsmasq and iptables installed on the host, but I stop the service during this test.

- os: centos 7
- docker: 19.03.2

Comment: you could try a few things for further debug this. First, explicitly pass the dns servers with `--dns 10.10.10.1` and `--dns 10.10.10.2`. If that doesn't work either, use `dig` or `nslookup` to determine which DNS server is actually the container using. If you see it's going to Google (8.8.8.8), that means that the container cannot reach your DNS servers and it's falling back to Google, so here you can debug why it's not able to reach your servers.